# How to spree sidebar of admin using deface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, spree, deface

Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'admin/shared/_sidebar',:name => 'blog',:insert_after =>'#main-sidebar',:text => 'text message')
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
Deface::Override.new(virtual_path: 'spree/admin/users/edit',
                    name: 'remove_sidebar',
                    remove: 'erb[loud]:contains("spree/admin/users/sidebar")')
```